# How do I transpose a dataframe after groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this table

| port | valueA | valueB | valueC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.1 | 58.2 | 0.09 |
| 2 | 3.09 | 58.3 | 0.1 |
| 3 | 3.09 | 58.15 | 0.09 |
| 4 | 3.11 | 58.2 | 0.1 |
| 1 | 3.1 | 58.25 | 0.09 |
| 2 | 3.1 | 58.25 | 0.09 |
| 3 | 3.08 | 58.15 | 0.09 |
| 4 | 3.09 | 58.1 | 0.09 |

I would like to group based on 'port' and then have them as columns in a new dataframe that has valueA as rows, like this:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.1 | 3.09 | 3.09 | 3.11 |
| 3.1 | 3.1 | 3.08 | 3.09 |

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'port': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
         'valueA': [3.1, 3.09, 3.09, 3.11, 3.1, 3.1, 3.08, 3.09], 
         'valueB': [58.2, 58.3, 58.15, 58.2, 58.25, 58.25, 58.15, 58.1], 
         'valueC': [0.09, 0.1, 0.09, 0.1, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

**Code**

```
grp = df.groupby('port').cumcount()
df.set_index([grp, 'port'])['valueA'].unstack().rename_axis('', axis=1)
```

output:

```
    1       2       3       4
0   3.1     3.09    3.09    3.11
1   3.1     3.10    3.08    3.09
```

**Intermediate**

df & grp:

```
df                                      grp
    port    valueA  valueB  valueC      
0   1       3.10    58.20   0.09        0
1   2       3.09    58.30   0.10        0
2   3       3.09    58.15   0.09        0
3   4       3.11    58.20   0.10        0
4   1       3.10    58.25   0.09        1
5   2       3.10    58.25   0.09        1
6   3       3.08    58.15   0.09        1
7   4       3.09    58.10   0.09        1
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code gives the expected answer:

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=df.groupby('port').cumcount(), columns='port', values='valueA', aggfunc='first').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df1)

port    1     2     3     4
0     3.1  3.09  3.09  3.11
1     3.1  3.10  3.08  3.09
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the `groupby`-function of pandas and instead would use the underlying numpy array. As your port index seems repeat itself and seems to stay in sequence, you just select the values of `valueA` and rearrange them in the correct shape.

It would look like that:

```
data_array = data.values  # get the array representation of your data
valueA_grouped = data_array[:, 1:2].reshape((2,4))
valueB_grouped = data_array[:, 2:3].reshape((2,4))
valueC_grouped = data_array[:, 3:4].reshape((2,4))
```